# Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found. angular

Tags: angular

im working on old angular project ( v 10 )  every things is well , suddenly when i open now to continue my work , i launch the command **ng s** it display me this error :

```
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
```

i followed many solution like change the *"optimization": false* delete the *"defaultProject": "project",* but same error : also when i run *npm i* it didn't continue it install and display :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: mdb-angular-ui-kit@1.0.0-beta6
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@10.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^10.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/platform-browser, ng-zorro-antd)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^12.0.0" from mdb-angular-ui-kit@1.0.0-beta6
npm ERR! node_modules/mdb-angular-ui-kit
npm ERR!   mdb-angular-ui-kit@"^1.0.0-beta6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/animations@12.2.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^12.0.0" from mdb-angular-ui-kit@1.0.0-beta6
npm ERR!   node_modules/mdb-angular-ui-kit
npm ERR!     mdb-angular-ui-kit@"^1.0.0-beta6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

i check the angular.json , package.json and no error displayed ,
angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/src/inline-svg/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.less",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "project:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "project:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "f6bd3c7d-ce71-47d6-820f-c375f083bbb4"
  }
}
```

and the package.json :

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.4",
    "json-server": "^0.17.3",
    "mdb-angular-ui-kit": "^1.0.0-beta6",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^10.1.2",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "primeng-lts": "^9.2.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

how can i fix it , And thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error.

It is a warning message telling you that `ng serve` should not be used in production. It is a development server intended for local development.

For production you would use `ng build`.